# Node JS - Acute Cannot Find Module Error

Tags: node.js, express

When I am trying to execute this code it gives an error which is confusing me a little.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var validator = require('node-mongoose-validator');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

var routes = require('./routes');
var route_add_user = require('./routes/add_user');
```

the error reads

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module './routes'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodefiles\new\server.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Please help me with this problem. Most probably I'm missing something or something problematic is there which is basic but maybe I am overlooking it.

Comment: It looks like routes is a directory, why are you trying to require a directory? What are you trying to accoplish?

Comment: To require routes you need an index.js file within your routes directory.

Comment: Thanks @realseanp problem solved!